# Use of self = [super init] in custom init method of NSObject subclass

Tags: objective-c, ios, oop

I am subclassing NSObject

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {

}
-(id)customInit;
@end
```

and implementing a custom init method in it,

```
-(id)customInit
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        return self;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

and creating an instance of MyClass as below

```
MyClass *myClassInstance = [[MyClass alloc]customInit];
```

Now my question is, what will I miss if I use an customInit method without self = [super init]; like below,

```
  -(id)customInit
    {
       return self;
    }
```

**Will I miss anything from the NSObject class which is the super class?** Thanks

Comment: As a side note, the name `init` has special meaning with regards to memory management that is different from `customInit`.  For the former, the static analyzer plans for +1 reference count and the latter +0.  If you want a custom `init` that is not just `init`, you should do something like `initCustom`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I don't [super init] in my customInit method, I will be missing the work done by the init method of NSObject. But otherwise I will have access to all the methods of super class and its protocols as I am inheriting it.

Comment: You're probably just citing a fantasy example, but it's worth noting  that calling your init "customInit" instead of "initFoo" breaks with convention and will likely confuse other developers.  In this case above, just call the method "init".

Comment: @JessBowers Yes, I am aware of that. I just wanna know whats happening behind the scene. :)

Answer (score 2):

No, you won't miss anything. From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/init):

> The `init` method defined in the `NSObject` class does no initialization; it simply returns `self`.

But, I would still recommend calling `self = [super init]` in order to future proof your code in case you ever decide to change the base class, for example.